# Graphing libraries for the browser

Tags: python

I need to plot graphs by taking information from the web browser. I have seeen matplotlib, however that gives an error: vcvarsall.bat is not prsent. Apparently i have to install Visual Studio 2008 package. I have tried plot.ly and you can't embed the graphs on to the webpage.
What libraries or modules could i use?

Comment: I've answered this question [before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17065122/1624921)

Comment: Im aware of that. But i can't install VS 2008. I have to look at something else

Comment: You don't need to, just install visual c++ 2008 or above, and thats free.

Comment: And what about setting the variable?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html

Comment: Now i can't find a download for visual c++ 08

Comment: Actually, you do not need to do any of that. Just download from the link above, according to your version of windows, and no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of Graphs you trying to embed in the webpage. If u r collecting some time sensitive data, then i think RRD tool will be good enough. But it entirely depends on the data that u want to generate the graph for..
In case of RRD tool there is a python API also available but which looks almost same to the console commands of RRDtool. :(

Comment: I will take info from a user from the browser and plot a simple histogram on the webserver. How can i do this?

Comment: well, in that case i am no expert but [this](http://www.flotcharts.org/) might come handy.. even I am looking for a better answer than mine :)